# Interact with non standard control via codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I'm using a CMS plugin with Microsoft Dynamics which features its own controls etc.

I have the following control within a listview, that I need to detect and then potentially update from the CodeBehind file. I know how to do this with a standard control such as a Panel, Div, TextBox etc but dont know how to do it with a control like this.

```
<crm:Property DataSourceID="Event" PropertyName="Adx_Summary" EditType="html" runat="server"/>
```

I'm also sure that this is something I NEED to know long term for other similar scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just give it an ID and then work with it like any other control:

```
<crm:Property DataSourceID="Event" PropertyName="Adx_Summary" EditType="html" runat="server" id="myCustomControl" />
```

In code:

```
myCustomControl.WhatEverItSupports();
```

Of course, this is if this tag is not part of another control and is nested within some sort of template. I can't deduce that from your question

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to mention it is inside a listview. Ill update my OP. Thanks. Any help you can offer in this circumstance?

Comment: If this is templated than you cannot get a reference, as there will be more than one instance on the page. If not, you could use `Page.FindControl("myCustomControl")` This will give you an object of type Control, which you then need to cast to the correct type

Comment: Its inside the <ItemTemplate> of thats what you mean? How do I cast it to the correct type? Sorry for the newb questions.

Comment: If it's inside the ItemTemplate, that means there are multiple instances on the page, so getting a reference to it doesn't make sense as you don't know how many there will be, nor do you know which one you will be referencing. What is exactly that you want to do?

Comment: I want to grab each one after it is databound, then based on its content do pick which div to reveal. Normally in the ItemDatabound event i would do something like ((Panel)e.itemFindControl("myControl")).Visible = True for example

Comment: To be more specific, in this instance I want to grab the content of the control which will essentially be a string. Although the control doesnt have a '.Text' property as would say a textbox.

Comment: The method I suggested earlier looks inside its children to see wether there's a control with the given name. If so, it will return it. You just need to cast it to the correct type: `YourControlType myControl =   theContainer.FindControl("myCustomControl") as YourControlType` What you need to find out is how to get a reference to the container. I'm not really sure if that info is available in the databound event

Comment: I realise how wierd this question must have seemed, and although I knew what you were saying in terms of controls Im familiar with I never thought to try and cast it as a Property control. It seems to be working now, so that for pointing out the obvious and helping me look at it from a basics point of view.